# How would I make this role specific?

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to make the following role-specific but it applies to every role in WooCommerce. What am I doing wrong?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'spyr_set_min_num_products' );
function spyr_set_min_num_products() {
    
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
        global $woocommerce;

        
        $targeted_role = 'wholesale';  
        $minimum_num_products = 50;
             
        
        $cart_num_products = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;
            
        
        if( $cart_num_products < $minimum_num_products ) {
            // Display our error message
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Minimum of %s products is required for wholesale accounts before checking out.</strong>' 
                . '<br />Current number of items in the cart: %s.',
                $minimum_num_products,
                $cart_num_products ),
            'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set a minimum number of products requirement before checking out
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'spyr_set_min_num_products' );
function spyr_set_min_num_products() {
    // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages & userrole matches
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
        
        // Check current user role
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;
    
        if ( empty($roles) ) {
            $roles[] = 'guest';
        }
        
        if ( in_array( 'wholesale', $roles ) ) {
            global $woocommerce;
            
            // Set the minimum number of products before checking out
            $minimum_num_products = 50;
            
            // Get the Cart’s total number of products
            $cart_num_products = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;
            
            // Compare values and add an error is Cart’s total number of products
            // happens to be less than the minimum required before checking out.
            // Will display a message along the lines of
            // A Minimum of 20 products is required before checking out. (Cont. below)
            // Current number of items in the cart: 6
            if( $cart_num_products < $minimum_num_products ) {
                wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Minimum of %s products is required for wholesale accounts before checking out.</strong>' 
                . '<br />Current number of items in the cart: %s.',
                $minimum_num_products,
                $cart_num_products ),
                'error' );
            }
        }
    }
}
```